# Visual Studio Property Sheet properties not showing up

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

**Symptom:**

Visual Studio property sheet properties not showing up after add existing property.

**Repro:**

1. Create property sheet according to Microsoft's recommended steps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx#bkmkPropertySheets
2. Copy *.props file to a different project's directory
3. Add this existing property sheet to project.
4. Open property sheet in Visual Studio. No properties are shown.

The .props file will have properties, but builds will fail and VS won't see it.

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround:**
Close and Open all instances of Visual Studio. Examine property sheet. Settings will appear.